# Best survey platform?

Tags: sql-server, iis

Looking for a (preferably open-source) survey tool, that I can run on IIS with MSSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Windows SharePoint Services](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/fx100503841033.aspx) - it's not Open Source but it won't cost you anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found [phpESP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpesp/) to be really good. Open source, runs on Windows (you'll have install PHP), but I'm not sure it works with MS SQL. You can export the results to Excel if necessary.

[eWeek says it works for them](http://www.eweek.com/c/a/Linux-and-Open-Source/OpenSource-Survey-Tool-phpESP-Stands-Test-of-Time/), so its tried and tested.